# No authentication challenges found in Twitter post

Tags: android, twitter4j

I used the following code to post to Twitter. But I'm getting `11-06 17:11:28.811: D/Twitter Update Error(22688): No authentication challenges found` error in logcat and status doesn't get posted. The same code works in another application.

update:

In my app any number of users can register through Twitter. I used to store both the tokens in db for a particular user after successful login. If different user likes to share through Twitter, I reset the accesstoken, and allow the login dialog to appear, and store that users tokens. If tokens are present in the db for a particular user, I directly get the tokens from db and used that.

```
try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token
                access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token,
                        access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                        .getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this
               try {

                    // Access Token
                    access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                            PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                    // Access Token Secret
                    access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                            PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token,
                            access_token_secret);
                    final Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("twitterConsumerKey", "twitterSecreatKey");
                    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

                    // Update status
                    twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

                    Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    // Error in updating status
                    Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthAccessToken("ACCESS_TOKEN");
        builder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("TOKEN_SECRET");
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey("CLIENT_ID");
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("CLIENT_SECRET");
        OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(builder.build());
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(auth);
        twitter.updateStatus("TEXT TO POST");
```

Comment: @Manikandan are your device Time Zone and Time,Date all correct?

Comment: Yes, It is set to automatic date and time. And the time zone is correct.